# Can indexedDB be used in a Google Hangout?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, google-hangouts

I've having some issues accessing window.indexedDB from a Hangout app.  I'm assuming its because of security issues.  Does indexedDB exist in an iframe?  I also don't have permission to access window.top.indexedDB.  Is it possible to have persistent storage to last from one hangout to another?  How about on disk (out of RAM) storage within the same hangout session?

Comment: Have you tried localStorage?  Also, if you post some code and some errors, others might help.

Comment: We could use more info - certainly. A code sample would be best. But I can guess at your issues based on what you've said and it suggests to me you're looking for information about IDB across domains. I've offered the best answer I can based on the information provided.

Comment: If you can get any data from Google Handout frame, you deserve a security bug bounty.

Answer (score 0):

> Does indexedDB exist in an iframe?

Not on its own. IndexedDB is exposed as an API on the DOM. When unprefixed, you can find it at `window.indexedDB`.

It certainly can be used from within a frame. When IDB is used in an iFrame, it will store it's data on the framed content's hostname according to the [same-origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy). In essence this means that you can access data from the same domain but not across domains. Note that "same domain" in context of same-origin means a matching tuple of *domain, protocol and port*.

If you're running into parent/child issues with your implementation for Google Hangout, I would check your frame's hostname and compare it to the parent domain. You can do that in Chrome by popping dev tools and selecting the `iframe` rather than the `<top frame>` and seeing if the location values match up.

[image]

Something like this should do the trick:

```
console.log( [window.location.protocol, '//', window.location.hostname, window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : ''].join('') );
```

If you need to talk across domains, protocols or ports use the `iframe` [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)() interface.